# Check if email address contains not allowed characters

Tags: vba, ascii

I'm using VBA "Asc" function to return the ASCII code of each character in an email address.
If the ASCII code is **not in certain range** the function should return the not valid (if not digit, not alphabet, not "@" and "_" and ".") character's position.
The code never returns the right result.

```vb
Function FirstNotValid(xStr As String) As Long
    Dim xChar As Integer
    Dim xPos As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 1 To Len(xStr)
        xChar = Asc(Mid(xStr, I, 1))
        If xChar < 45 Or (58 < xChar < 64) Or (90 < xChar < 97) Or 122 < xChar Then
            xPos = I
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    FirstNotValid = xPos
End Function

Sub test()
    Debug.Print FirstNotValid("ab?!an@gmail.com")
End Sub
```

For the example used to call this function, it should return 3. The result is always 1.
I know the "?" character ASCII code is 33, which should not skip the if condition, but it did.

Comment: By stepping through your test code above, both conditions `(58 < xChar < 64)` and `(90 < xChar < 97)` are evaluating to `True`. Because you are joining the conditions with the `Or` operator, if ANY of the conditions evaluate `True` it will enter the code block and execute `xPos = I Exit For`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative method I could think of - Split `xStr` to array of bytes and then use Select statement to filter through a range of "allowed characters":

```
Function FirstNotValid(xStr As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim charArr() As Byte
    
    charArr = StrConv(xStr, vbFromUnicode)
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(charArr)
        Select Case charArr(i)
            Case 46         '.
            Case 48 To 57   '0-9
            Case 64 To 90   '@ + A-Z
            Case 95         '_
            Case 97 To 122  'a-z
            Case Else   'Any character that falls out of allowed range above
                FirstNotValid = i + 1
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next i
End Function
```

Note: This will not work on Mac as the argument `vbFromUnicode` for StrConv is not available on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, your code is evaluating `True` for the statement

```
If xChar < 45 Or (58 < xChar < 64) Or (90 < xChar < 97) Or 122 < xChar Then
```

This causes the `If...Then` block to be entered, thus returning 1 on the first iteration of your code.

You can consider changing `If` statement conditions to only compare `xChar` to one value per condition.

I would approach the code slightly differently and use an `Array()` to house a 'blacklist' of characters, then iterate each character of the string compared to each element of the array - If matched, return the character position.

```
Function InvalidCharacterPosition(ByVal StringToCheck As String) As Long

Dim ArrayElement As Long
Dim CharPosition As Long
Dim BlackListCharacters() As Variant
BlackListCharacters() = Array("?", "/", "<", ">", "*")

For CharPosition = 1 To Len(StringToCheck)
    For ArrayElement = LBound(BlackListCharacters) To UBound(BlackListCharacters)
        If Asc(Mid(StringToCheck, CharPosition, 1)) = Asc(BlackListCharacters(ArrayElement)) Then
            InvalidCharacterPosition = CharPosition
        End If
    Next ArrayElement
Next CharPosition

End Function
```

Much the same as your code design but I feel this way is a bit easier to understand and follow, along with easier to modify (i.e. just add any extra or remove any required characters from the Array easily without changing the rest of the code).

Calling this the same as your test returns 3:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print InvalidCharacterPosition("ab?!an@gmail.com")
End Sub
```